# How do I prevent iTunes from opening my DVD drive when I close iTunes?

Tags: windows, windows-10, itunes

Every time I close iTunes it makes my DVD drive open. How do I stop it from opening the drive? I'm on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: A ton of people have this issue and I don't think Apple has fixed it yet. Does your drive have a disc in it, or no disc?

Comment: @DrZoo I have a disc in it, but that shouldnt matter as me watching blurays has no relation to what I do with itunes

Comment: @My1 that is a somewhat correct logical assumption but does not necessarily mean it isn't the cause of the issue, as described [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8557341). In the early days of iTunes, many people had disc's with music on it to be imported into iTunes. Upon quitting the application, it would be a reminder to remove your disc. iTunes has also been replaced and it's hard telling how long that "feature" has been present. It surely will not be fixed.

Comment: well maybe that should maybe trigger (optionally) at the end of an import rather than when closing itunes. Just Like Windows media Player of all things.